# URI too large when passing base64 string

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, json.net

I am getting an error, http error 414. The request url is too long, when trying to pass a base64 string to a webservice. I have read in multiple forums that I should be using POST to transmit the data but I cannot find any examples that seem to work for me.

Below is the sample code that I receive the error with.

```
Dim syncClient = New WebClient()

Dim url As String = "https://login.someurl.com=" & vin & "&action=attachdoc&transaction_id" & transactionID & "&filename=" & filename & "&docdata="

Dim jsonstring As String = syncClient.UploadString(url, base64String)
Dim node As XNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonstring, "Results")
Return node.ToString
```

I have also attempted the POST sample code below with no luck. gives the same error of URI to long.

```
   ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST"
    ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    Dim postData As String = base64String
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    ' Get the request stream.
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    ' Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    ' Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close()
    ' Get the response.
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    ' Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    ' Read the content.
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    ' Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
```

Comment: How big is `base64String`? many web-servers impose limits on the length of the URI they will allow

Comment: also,  it looks like you have `base64String` in both the query-string and the body; is the one in the query-string redundant?

Comment: I changed my original post to remove the base64 string from the url string. I was testing a few changes before and forgot that item in the url string before posting this.

Comment: Character count is about 62,000

Comment: so... does removing it from the url fix the problem?

Comment: No, the same error is still there